# How to pass user id from view to Form's init method?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have reviewed many questions/answers for hours and applied many techniques but I couldn't pass the user id to the form **init**() method, it always gives errors like "**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'". Anyone knows the reason?

Form, updated as requested in the comment:

```
class ChildChoreForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = ChildChore
    exclude = ('child',)
    fields = '__all__'

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    super(ChildChoreForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['chore'].queryset = Chore.objects.filter(created_by=self.request.user)

ChildChoreFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Child,  ChildChore, form=ChildChoreForm, extra=1)
```

View:

```
class ChildChoreUpdate(UpdateView):
  model = Child
  success_url = reverse_lazy('children-list') 
  form_class = ChildChoreFormSet

  def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    if hasattr(self, 'object'):
        kwargs.update({'request': self.request})
    return kwargs
```

The Errors I'm getting after opening the updaet web page:

```
Internal Server Error: /chore/children/23
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 89, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 190, in get
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 133, in get
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
  File "C:\Python\py_projects\children_chores\chore\views.py", line 202, in get_context_data
    data = super(ChildChoreUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs )
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 66, in get_context_data
    kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 33, in get_form
    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 898, in __init__
    super().__init__(data, files, prefix=prefix, queryset=qs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 569, in __init__
    super().__init__(**defaults)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'
Internal Server Error: /chore/children/23
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 89, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 190, in get
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 133, in get
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
  File "C:\Python\py_projects\children_chores\chore\views.py", line 202, in get_context_data
    data = super(ChildChoreUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs )
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 66, in get_context_data
    kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 33, in get_form
    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 898, in __init__
    super().__init__(data, files, prefix=prefix, queryset=qs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 569, in __init__
    super().__init__(**defaults)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace for the error?

Comment: Also show us the code where you define `ChildChoreFormSet` as that is where the issue most likely is. You are passing a `request` argument to the *formset* constructor, not the *form* constructor.

Comment: updated as requested, thanks in advanced.

Comment: Are you using custom form or django model based form?

Comment: it is model based form... I have a form for filling/updating a child data and under that a formset for the chores which has a title and other fields, but the titles is a drop down  list created by different users. So, I want to filter it based on the current user(father/mother). In addition to that I want to know why I cannot pass the request to the formset, since I may use the same soultion for different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have set up your form to accept a `request` argument in `__init__`, but you are initialising a *formset*, not a *form*. You need to modify the formset to [accept that same argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#passing-custom-parameters-to-formset-forms) and pass it to the forms in the formset:

```
# First define a base class that overrides __init__ and get_form_kwargs
from django.forms import BaseFormSet

class BaseChildChoreFormSet(BaseFormSet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Handle the request argument that you are passing on init
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_kwargs(self, index):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(index)
        # Add request to the kwargs that are passed to the form on init
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs

# Now set up your formset using this class
ChildChoreFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Child,  ChildChore, form=ChildChoreForm, formset=BaseChildChoreFormSet, extra=1)
```